# Docker and connections between containers

Tags: php, linux, nginx, docker, linux-containers

I'm trying create connections between docker's containers. One container with php5-fpm and second with nginx.

Config for php5-fpm default, just few changes:

```
listen = 9000

listen.allowed_clients =
```

and nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/testing;
    index index.php

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 192.168.1.2:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Then i tried create connections with https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework, that's why `fastcgi_pass 192.168.1.2:9000;`.I tried with IP direct from container, but nothing.

and when i'm trying open page with lynx i have BadGateway.

I tried post port MASTER_PORT=$(sudo docker port $MASTER_ID 9000), but nothing...
ping goes with no problem. Telnet to port 9000 from nginx keeps open few seconds and then "Connection closed by..."

Who could explain what i'm doing wrong?
Thx!

/*EDIT*/
I tried change fastcgi_pass to 172.17.42.1:9000; (address for docker0 on host machine) and then start  tcpdump on host machine:

tcpdump -i docker0 port 9000

and i have:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on docker0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:24:54.529572 IP 172.17.0.20.40932 > 172.17.42.1.9000: Flags [S], seq 141160046, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1235770 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:24:54.529594 IP 172.17.42.1.9000 > 172.17.0.20.40932: Flags [S.], seq 2944341886, ack 141160047, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1235770 ecr 1235770,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:24:54.529605 IP 172.17.0.20.40932 > 172.17.42.1.9000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 1235770 ecr 1235770], length 0
10:24:54.530324 IP 172.17.0.20.40932 > 172.17.42.1.9000: Flags [P.], seq 1:665, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 1235771 ecr 1235770], length 664
10:24:54.530387 IP 172.17.42.1.9000 > 172.17.0.20.40932: Flags [.], ack 665, win 124, options [nop,nop,TS val 1235771 ecr 1235771], length 0
10:24:54.530534 IP 172.17.42.1.44233 > 172.17.0.12.9000: Flags [S], seq 1354597292, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1235771 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:24:54.530549 IP 172.17.0.12.9000 > 172.17.42.1.44233: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1354597293, win 0, length 0
10:24:54.531044 IP 172.17.42.1.9000 > 172.17.0.20.40932: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 665, win 124, options [nop,nop,TS val 1235771 ecr 1235771], length 0
```

Thus packets goes between containers...but why BadGateway?

Comment: Using php-fpm 5.4.16 in the CentOS 7 container made the above fail. The issue was that `listen.allowed_clients` must be omitted. `listen.allowed_clients = ` generates `WARNING: [pool www] child 68 said into stderr: "ERROR: Wrong IP address '' in listen.allowed_clients"`

Answer (score 22):

Starting with docker 0.6.5 you don't need pipework for that kind of scenario, you can use the new container linking feature. Basically, you tell docker to make a port from a container available to another container.

It's pretty easy to do, too.

What you want to do is have a container with php5-fpm (let's call this container `php5-fpm`) configured to listen on port 9000 and run it like so:

```
docker run -d -p 9000 -name php php5-fpm /usr/sbin/php5-fpm -F
```

We run `php5-fpm` with the `-F` flag so that it does not daemonize. As you can see, we use `-name` to explicitely name our container. We will use this name to reference it in the link we are going to create with the nginx container.

Then you can run your nginx (called `nginx`) container:

```
docker run -i -t -link php:php nginx /bin/bash
```

The `-link` option tells docker to link the `php` container under the alias `php`. The alias is mandatory.

We now have a shell in our nginx container, and we can retrieve the mapped ip and port of the `php5-fpm` container using the `env` command:

```
root@061fe34bd07b:/# env
HOSTNAME=061fe34bd07b
TERM=xterm
PHP_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.44:9000
PHP_PORT_9000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
PHP_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT=9000
SHLVL=1
HOME=/
PHP_PORT_9000_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.44:9000
PHP_NAME=/crimson_squirrel9/php
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
PHP_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.44
container=lxc
OLDPWD=/
_=/usr/bin/env
```

There are a number of interesting env vars here. The one we are looking for is `PHP_PORT`, since it gives the most complete information about the linked container:

```
PHP_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.44:9000
```

You can now configure nginx's php5-fpm upstream to 172.17.0.44:9000, start it, and check that it works:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
curl http://127.0.0.1/index.php
```

Voila ! I skipped provisioning and configuration of containers since you seem to have got that right already ;)

Link to the official linking tutorials, using redis: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/linking_into_redis/

Comment: Thx a lot @GeoffreyBachelet!!! I saw manual about linking_into_redis, but..I've followed all steps from your manual..but again Bad Gateway..

Comment: Do you have Dockerfiles to build your containers that we could use to debug that issue, or could you push your containers to the docker index?

Comment: Every time you'll rebuild the PHP5 container, his IP address will change. Can't we handle this with the env variable $PHP5_PORT ? Or are we forced to run the nginx container with --link in order to discover the IP address of the php5 container? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

This may fix the issue:

```
listen = [::]:9000
;listen.allowed_clients =
```

This should allow any client to connect to the PHP-FPM container. The key is the "[::]:" which I found in the official PHP Docker repo.

**Reasoning**

PHP-FPM has a `listen.client_allowed` setting which allows you to set a list of IPs that can connect, or leave blank for any IP to connect. However, even with it being left blank, the issue still persisted. Digging into the official PHP-FPM repo, I discovered that you also need to set                                                       `listen = [::]:9000` which then began to allow any IP to connect.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is exactly what I'm looking for last 2 days :(

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old but it comes up high in Google so let me post a reply.

I have the same sort of problem although I get a "file not found."
PHP-fpm and Nginx in different containers are problematic because Nginx sends php-fpm the location of the to-be executed php file, not the file. So the file has to be present in both containers.

[See my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055627/docker-nginx-and-php5-fpm-dockers-are-not-talking)

Answer (score 0):

With the nginx/php5-fpm setup, I've received bad gateway errors when php5-fpm wasn't running. So, are you sure php-fpm is running in your other container? I've noticed that php-fpm WILL die in a container unless I run it with the -D option from the command line. So

```
 ~$: php5-fpm -D
```

I also run my nginx server with the `daemon off;` setting to ensure that nginx does not self-daemonize, otherwise docker will terminate the container as soon as the nginx process finishes execution. However, since you're getting a Bad Gateway response from nginx already, this either isn't your problem or you've already accounted for it in your nginx configuration.

Comment: @Eli_Hooten, with option -D my php5-fpm container can't start..just with -F and nginx configured with daemon off;